# Is it possible to use a C++ library to run local PHP for use in an in-app web browser?

Tags: php, c++, user-interface, local

I was wondering if it was possible to run PHP code locally for use in a native C++ desktop application. As an overview, I would like to use a few HTML5/JS/PHP libraries/tools as components of the GUI inside of a desktop application.

I intend on using something like Awesomium or Berkelium as an in-app browser and GUI. Is there any way to do this locally and cross platform (windows/linux) in a manner that does not involve starting any sort of web server?

If a web server is required, does anyone have any suggestions for a good way to sandbox it to only allow localhost, while at the same time being compatible with Windows and Linux?

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly possible, but for all but the simplest of cases (e.g. just running a simple script and showing it's output) you would probably end up implementing parts of the CGI stack yourself.

A much easier way is to just run a web server that does all that for you. How you would restrict it to localhost only is up the webserver you choose but isn't usually a difficult task, in the popular ones at least.